# Linear Algebra-invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $V$ is a real vector space and $T\in \mathcal L (V)$ has no (real) eigenvalues.

Prove that
every subspace of $V$ invariant under $T$ has even dimension.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I have two questions: 1) what is $TL(V)$, and 2) what did you try to solve this problem?

Comment: TL(V) means T is a linear operator from V to V. Only thing i could do is thinking about the characteristic polynomial..

Comment: Presumably what is meant is $T \in L(V)$.

Comment: You must assume your vector space, or at least the subspace, is finite-dimensional:  there are examples with infinite-dimensional invariant subspaces.

Comment: Yes, it must be finite dimensional but i still can't show it.

Comment: **Hint:** we can apply the intermediate value theorem to any odd-degree polynomial.

Comment: Let T: R^3 --> R^3 be a linear functional.can we say R^3 has a T invariant subspace of dimension 2?

Answer (score 2):

More precisely (allowing for infinite-dimensional vector spaces): there is no finite-dimensional invariant subspace with odd dimension.

Hint: consider the characteristic polynomial of the restriction of $T$ to an odd-dimensional invariant subspace.  What do you know about real roots of polynomials of odd degree?

Answer (score 0):

Assume to the contrary that there exists a $T$-invariant subspace $W$ that has odd dimension. Consider $T|_W$, the restriction of $T$ on $W$. Let $f(t)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $T|_W$, since $T$ has no real eigenvalues, so is $T|_W$, and by the Fundamental Theroem of Algebra, $f(t)=a(t-c_1)...(t-c_{2k-1})$ where $c_i \in \mathbb C$ for all $i$ (not necessarily distinct) and $a \in \mathbb R$. But this contradicts to $f(t)$ has real coefficients.

Comment: Or using the fact that real polynomials of odd degrees must have a real root as suggested by Robert